# Read continuous feed from CouchDB using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, couchdb, jsonp

I want to listen for continuous changes from CouchDB using jQuery - now this works:

```
http://localhost:5984/testdb/_changes?feed=continuous
```

which means that I get a new line of json every time there is a db update - but how do I read updates off this URL using jQuery?

I tried using this but it doesn't work:

```
$.ajax(
{
  url : "http://localhost:5984/testdb/_changes?feed=continuous&callback=?",
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function(data)
  {
    alert(data.results.length);
  }
});
```

**Edit**: $.ajax calls the "success" function and returns immediately, it doesn't "poll" for changes.. (timeline column for ajax column in image below is 16ms)

[image]

And no, it isn't a cross-domain ajax problem - I can see in fireBug there is a response with the right number of elements

So any guidance/advice would be appreciated - it doesn't have to be jQuery - plain old javscript would do as well

Comment: `feed=continuous` is intended for usage at server side. In the browser, use `feed=longpoll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can think of two good ways to do this.

1. Using a timer (ie., `setTimeout();`), run the AJAX call on the changes feed every X seconds. You will also store the last sequence number that you received, so that you can tell the changes feed which sequence number to start at the next time you poll. This will prevent duplicate data and make the responses smaller.
2. Depending on what browsers you need to support, you might be able to use the EventSource API. Here is a jQuery implementation: https://github.com/rwldrn/jquery.eventsource

Comment: Thanks Sam - I am doing 1. right now... but I would like to use the continuous feed method - and I can't use 2, I need to support as many browsers as possible

Comment: So, this is generally "not possible" with HTTP because it is a stateless protocol. However, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming) for methods of doing it. What you're doing now is one of those methods.

Comment: Yes, Comet is right - thanks for pointing it out - in case I manage to write the code to handle this, I will post it here

Comment: Awesome sami, glad that I could be of help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As [Gjorgji Tashkovski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760401/gjorgji-tashkovski) mentioned `feed=continuous` is intended for server-side, you can use `feed=longpoll` for your use case.

```
(function($) {
  // this is a recursive function
  function longpoll(database, last_seq) {
    var url = "/" + database + "/_changes?feed=longpoll";
    // If we don't have a sequence number, then see where we are up to.
    if (last_seq) {
      url = url + "&since=" + last_seq;
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // Now we need to see what to do with the data.
        console.log(document.data.results);

        // And set up the re-run of the fetch query.
        // recursive call
        longpoll(database, data.last_seq);
      }
    })
  }
  
  $.couch.longpoll = longpoll;
}(jQuery));
```

This example source code came from this now archived blog:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170821130003/http://schinckel.net/2012/01/22/jquery-long-poll-for-couchdb-changes./