# CouchDB - Continuous feed using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, couchdb, polling

After reading a similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232391/read-continuous-feed-from-couchdb-using-ajax-jquery), I'm curious as to whether this is at all possible?

I understand I can make the below work, by wrapping in a setInterval function, which repeatedly calls the check-for-changes function, but I would much rather use continuous polling.

The database regularly gets updated every minute during peak times, but seems a waste to keep polling the database during off-peak times...

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:5984/db?callback=?', function(db) {
    console.log(db.update_seq);
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:5984/db/_changes?since='+db.update_seq+'&feed=continuous&callback=?', function(changes) {
        console.log(changes);
    });
});
```

Firebug shows when a change is indeed made, something happens, but only null is returned.

I'm also on the same domain, calling a page from localhost/index.php

Comment: I am not 100% sure, however I *think* the raw XHR API does allow long connections with COMET-style updates; however jQuery does not expose this, for simplicity. With jQuery, there is a complete query and a complete response, no streaming. If I am correct, I would love to see a jQuery plugin to fix this because I want it too!

Comment: @jhs, have to agree with you there! I remember a while ago looking into this same thing, and having to settle with my current approach (setInterval/long-polling). Let me know if you discover anything! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using continuous or long-polling, you could instead adopt an adaptive strategy. Perhaps start at 1 minute intervals. If there are no updates, up it to 2 minutes, then 3, 4, 5 etc. If there are some updates then the interval can be modified to reflect the time until the next expected update.

Basically it all boils down to how important it is to you to actually get the notifications of updates in near-real-time and how large a delay you are willing to deal with.

Comment: thanks! im currently doing something along those lines for my solution. I guess I always feel a little nervous using setInterval...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concrete example of [Colin Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/760401/gjorgji-tashkovski)'s accepted answer:

```
(function($) {
  // this is a recursive function
  function longpoll(database, last_seq) {
    var url = "/" + database + "/_changes?feed=longpoll";
    // If we don't have a sequence number, then see where we are up to.
    if (last_seq) {
      url = url + "&since=" + last_seq;
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        // Now we need to see what to do with the data.
        console.log(document.data.results);

        // And set up the re-run of the fetch query.
        // recursive call
        longpoll(database, data.last_seq);
      }
    })
  }
  
  $.couch.longpoll = longpoll;
}(jQuery));
```

This example source code came from this now archived blog:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170821130003/http://schinckel.net/2012/01/22/jquery-long-poll-for-couchdb-changes./